# Unity , C# Error CS0012 : The type 'Color' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-game-engine, xceed

i use Unity version 2020.1.11f1

I am trying to create Docs using the Xceed library. However, every time I mention Color, I get the following error :
error CS0012: The type 'Color' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

example code:

```
s1.Color = Color.red;
s1.Bind( brazil, "Category", "Expenses" );
c.AddSeries( s1 );
```

I tried to use this : `[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter("System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]`

along with this code:

`s1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;`

and now the error looks like this:

`error CS1069: The type name 'Color' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.`

Comment: It thinks you want to use `System.Drawing.Color` ... make sure it uses `UnityEngine.Color` instead

Comment: I have no Color in the `System.Drowning` library. This is the problem, he suggests that I use either `UnityEngine.Color` or `Styles.Color`.

Comment: Exactly .. so use `UnityEngine.Color`

Comment: I just at the beginning of my question demonstrated the lack of work of this option.

Comment: No you didn't .. you just wrote `Color` and as it seems it automatically thinks you mean `System.Drawing.Color` .. which is not the case .. you don't want any reference to that assembly at all ... you want to use the type `UnityEngine.Color` ... Either explicitly like that or e.g. have `using UnityEngine;` or if you are using multiple namespaces that contain a `Color` have `using Color = UnityEngine.Color;` at the top of your script

Comment: When I hover over Color, I see which library it belongs to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the `Xceed` bundle had lost its reference to the `System.Drawning.Color` library or could not pull it up. When adding the library to the directory, the problem was solved.